# I want to design two images side to side using bootstrap irrespective of image dimensions but img doesn't adjust itself inside col tag

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

```
   <div class="container" style="background-color: aqua;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="nature.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="brown.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Image is not adjusting itself inside col-md-6

Answer (score 1):

You have to use class `w-100` for that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="background-color: aqua;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589987847444-08203b5e123c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60"
          class="w-100">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589987847444-08203b5e123c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60"
          class="w-100">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Same problem the images are not coming onto single line @fareed khan

Comment: But in my browser it shows on the same line: https://ibb.co/W6XFjHs, Also on the code snippet that i provided.

Comment: now its working probably I missed something thanks @fareed

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following tag for responsive image -

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

Refer to the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/).

Comment: the other image is coming on next line

Comment: Then use a responsive layout like row to align two images in same line. Refer to. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/